# Gradle's "local repository" similar to Maven?

Tags: maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Let's say i'm having 1 library that is used by 2 apps that are built with `Gradle`. How can i edit/compile the library independently from the apps (completely different folder in the file system) but be able to compile the apps using the library?

The problem is that by default the library and the app should be in the same project directory:

```
project
|--library
L--app
```

so app's `build.gradle` files look like:

```
compile(project(":library"))
```

This is a problem since it requires library files to be stored in the same folder where app folder is and since we have 2 apps it can't be achieved.

I'm having experience with `Maven` and it's solved the following way: the artifacts are saved in local Maven storage and can be referenced from the app so it does not matter where it is in file system. Similar solution for `Gradle`?

PS. This is the following question: if i'd like to use any 3rd-party library do i have to clone it in project folder and reference using `compile project ':library'`? Any way to clone it into completely independent file system location and reference just by 'groupId+artifactId+version'?

Comment: Gradle can publish a builded library into Maven Local Repository (`~/.m2` by default) too, like Maven do so. Just apply `maven` plugin and execute `install` task. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html

Comment: And if you want to use a 3rd-party library, just apply maven plugin, add maven central repository (or any other maven repository that contains the library you need) and then you can refer to that library by 'groupId+artifactId+version'.

Comment: yes, i know about maven plugin for Gradle and publishing maven artifacts into local maven repo. But it means that there is no such solution in Gradle and it looks strange. BTW, i know i can use maven artifacts published in public maven repos but not all the libs (or the last versions) are published. Still waiting for Gradle-way for my case..

Comment: @4ntoine Gradle does not have it's own way. Gradle re-uses existing dependency-management/artifact-repository solutions like maven and ivy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that by:

1. **sharing compiled library's bytecode**:

   - in the library's `build.gradle` you will add

     ```
     apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
     ```

     and "install" the artifact in local repository by executing `gradle publishToMavenLocal`
   - in your apps you will point to the published artifact and specify local maven repo as repository:

     ```
     repositories {
         mavenLocal()
     }
     dependencies {
         config "yourArtifactGAV"
     }
     ```
2. **sharing project sources and adding it as part of the build**

   - in the application directory you will add `settings.gradle` file:

     ```
     include $yourLibName
     def p = findProject(":$yourLibName")
     p.projectDir = new File(settingsDir, absolutePathToYourLibraryDir)
     ```
   - that way the library will be automatically compiled every time you compile the applications + you will add project level dependency to it

     ```
     dependencies {
         config project(':$yourLibName')
     }
     ```